# How to connect Postgresql in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I tried to connect PostgreSQL and laravel
I can see all data on pgAdmin.
But I can't connect the PostgreSQL on laravel project
Please help me
Thanks

.Env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=gotmold
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=Slack0206!
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class CurlController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

    }

    public function view(){
        $User = User::get()->count();
        print_r($User);
    }
}
```

I got this error
I already cleared cache

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select * from "users")
http://127.0.0.1:8000/view
```

Comment: Have you tried config:clear too?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes, i did

Comment: I would also check if default database connection is overwritten either in Model or in config/database.php.

Comment: It's a new project, nothing overwritten. tnx

Comment: I did the above way but my project still not working. Until when I run "php artisan config:clear" on my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Xampp on window 10
Then I enabled the extensions in php.ini again:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

It works well

Answer (score 0):

Find file php.inc in xampp ex:C:\xampp\php.
open file php.inc, find pgsql and delete accents ";" before extension

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple because you have an error in configuration files.

1. .ENV define connection and DB
2. In your database.php file in config directory you MUST DECLARE the connection in connections array.

Just only copy the mysql connection there and replace with your datas (user, db, password, host )

```
    'connections' => [
     
             'sqlite' => [
                 'driver'   => 'sqlite',
                 'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
                 'prefix'   => '',
             ],
     'mysql' => [
                 'driver'    => 'mysql',
                 'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
                 'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                 'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'my_db'),
                 'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'my_user'),
                 'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_password'),
                 'charset'   => 'utf8',
                 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                 'prefix'    => '',
                 'strict'    => false,
                 'engine'    => null,
             ],
     'pgsql' => [ REPLACE_HERE_YOUR_DATA]
```